# Blazor todoApp making

Tags: blazor

I need to make a ToDo list.
My task:
2 menu items are required.
It should be in the first menu: Tasks, adding a new task. There is a checkbox next to the task, if I tick the checkbox it should move to the second menu item for the completed tasks. In the second menu, where the completed tasks are placed, there should also be a checkbox next to the completed tasks, if active it will return to the first menu among the tasks.
It must be solved without a database. It is enough to store the data in the memory.
I want to store the data in a class type list.
I don't know how to access the list from both menus!
Anyone have any ideas?

I have 2 razor components.
I have a ToDoItem class.
One component has List
I need to access this list with the other componentw

Comment: [Polite].  See [mre].  I may be reading this wrong, and understand english is not your first language, but you appear to be defining some requirements and hoping someone will show you how to write your application.   You need to show what you've done so far and where you're stuck and need help.  " I want to store the data in a class type list. I don't know how to access the list from both menus! Anyone have any ideas?"  Maybe search for tutorials on how to build a basic Blazor application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parent component, you could make use of the [CascadingParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) attribute. This allows you to have a property on a parent component and access it from any descendant of it.

If your structure looks like this:

- Parent

  - child 1
  - child 2

In the parent you could do the following:

```html
<CascadingValue value=@todos>
    @* when you do not use routing *@
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
    @* 
     * or when your Parent inherits from LayoutComponentBase
     * and your Components define the page
     *@
    @Body
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private List<ToDoItem> todos = new List<ToDoItem>();
}
```

And in the components:

```html
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public List<ToDoItem> ToDos { get; set; }
}
```